# Table aliasing in update statement in RedShift

Tags: sql, sql-update, amazon-redshift

I have a sql statement which is as follows which I am trying to convert to Redshift.

```
update #tmpHist l 
set spread = lh.spread
from table1 lh 
where  
    l.id=lh.id
```

But it gives error as:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "l"
```

Is there a way to alias table without specifying entire table.

Comment: The documentation explicitly says that no alias is permitted:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UPDATE.html#r_UPDATE-synopsis.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

> UPDATE table_name SET column = { expression | DEFAULT } [,...]
>
> [ FROM fromlist ]
>
> [ WHERE condition ]

- Use a `FROM` clause to join in additional tables.

You can try this.

```
update #tmpHist  
set spread = lh.spread
from table1 lh 
where  
    #tmpHist.id=lh.id
```

or you can try to use `update .... join` for alias name.

```
update l 
set spread = lh.spread
from table1 lh join #tmpHist on l.id=lh.id
```